# Separate script-editor and AppleScript tags from each other

Tags: feature-request, tags

Before this recent question

- [Script Editor shows Error: No Error in JavaScript code for sending email](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/371589/apple-script-editor-error-0-no-error?noredirect=1)

taught me that JavaScript can also be used in Script Editor app, I had added AppleScript tag into it. After clarification, I tried to remove it and put the app's name. But both are synonyms.

[script-editor](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/script-editor) redirects to [applescript](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/applescript).

Can we have them separated?

Comment: not sure if tag edits are FRs.

Comment: Redirecting `script-editor` to `applescript` is odd, people can very well ask about one or the other (tool usage vs programming). We don‘t redirect `xcode` to `swift` (or `objective-c`) either... Can you make a proposal below as an answer for new tag descriptions?

Comment: sentence structure can have biases, so it definitely needs some edits. Also pls drop by in https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/2510/better-tags-for-ask-different

Comment: I dont think AppleScript needed any revisions https://apple.stackexchange.com/edit-tag-wiki/323

Answer (score 0):

[script-editor](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/script-editor)

It is a native code editor app for macOS used to write app automation scripts in AppleScript and JavaScript. Found in `/Applications/Utilities/`, it can edit, run, compile and save scripts in formats like .scpt, .scptd, .applescript, .app etc.

Comment: I have to disagree with "Often known as AppleScript Editor" as it was originally called Script Editor till MacOS X 10.6 and has been called Script Editor since OS X 10.10. It has been called  Script Editor and been known as Script Editor considerably longer then the very brief time it was called AppleScript Editor. IMO any use of the term AppleScript Editor should be a minor footnote in regards to describing Script Editor.

Comment: I suspected that too. But couldn't find a better opening. Please edit the CW.

Comment: references: https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/MacAutomationScriptingGuide/GettoKnowScriptEditor.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40016239-CH5-SW1 https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AppleScript_Editor I'd blame wikipedia for me using those words.